# Why the output parameter of my ADODB.Command does not retrieve a value when executing?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic, odbc, ado

I have a code in Classic ASP and SQL Server, the idea is simple, to have an stored procedure so you can insert a file but before that, the sp will check if the file already exists, after that will return an output parameter so I can check it on my asp page.

The problem is the returning value of the output parameter is nothing, I cann´t figure out where is the problem..

The SP is:

```
        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pi_usu_crear_cuenta]
         @msg_salida    char(1) OUTPUT  /* 0=Registro ya existe, 1=Insert satidfactorio, 2=Update Satidfactorio*/
        ,@usu_email     nvarchar(50)
        ,@usu_alias     nvarchar(50)
        ,@usu_password  nvarchar(50)
        ,@pai_cod       numeric(3,0)
        ,@usu_mayoriaedad char(1)
        ,@pk_pre        int
        ,@usu_respuesta nvarchar(50)

    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
       IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tm_usu_usuarios
                       WHERE usu_email = @usu_email)
       BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tm_usu_usuarios
               (usu_email
               ,usu_alias
               ,usu_password
               ,pai_cod
               ,usu_mayoriaedad
               ,pk_pre
               ,usu_respuesta
               )
         VALUES
               (
                @usu_email
               ,@usu_alias
               ,@usu_password
               ,@pai_cod
               ,@usu_mayoriaedad
               ,@pk_pre
               ,@usu_respuesta
                );
        Select @msg_salida = '1'
       END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
        Select @msg_salida = '2'
   END
    END
```

The Classic ASP is:

```
        Dim cmd2
        Dim Rs_crearcuenta     
        Const adCmdStoredProc = &H0004
        '---- ParameterDirectionEnum Values ----
        Const adParamInput          = &H0001
        Const adParamOutput         = &H0002
        Const adParamReturnValue    = &H0004
        '---- DataTypeEnum Values ----
        Const adInteger     = 3
        Const adChar        = 129
        Const adVarChar     = 200
        Const adVarWChar    = 202
        Const adNumeric     = 131

        Set cmd2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        Set cmd2.ActiveConnection = Session("Conexion")
        cmd2.CommandText = "pi_usu_crear_cuenta"
        cmd2.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

        cmd2.Parameters.Append cmd2.CreateParameter("@msg_salida",      adChar,         adParamOutput,      1)      
        cmd2.Parameters.Append cmd2.CreateParameter("@usu_email",       adVarChar,      adParamInput,       50, vEmail)     
        cmd2.Parameters.Append cmd2.CreateParameter("@usu_alias",       adVarChar,      adParamInput,       50, vAlias)     
        cmd2.Parameters.Append cmd2.CreateParameter("@usu_password",    adVarChar,      adParamInput,       50, vPassword)      

        SET param           =  cmd2.CreateParameter("@pai_cod",         adNumeric,      adParamInput,       3, null)
        param.Precision     = 3
        param.NumericScale  = 0
        param.Value         = vPais
        cmd2.Parameters.Append param    'NUMERIC

        cmd2.Parameters.Append cmd2.CreateParameter("@usu_mayoriaedad", adChar,         adParamInput,       1,  vMayoria_edad)      
        cmd2.Parameters.Append cmd2.CreateParameter("@pk_pre",          adInteger,      adParamInput,        ,  vPregunta)      
        cmd2.Parameters.Append cmd2.CreateParameter("@usu_respuesta",   adVarWChar,     adParamInput,       50, vRespuesta)     'NVARCHAR
        cmd2.Prepared = true

        Set Rs_crearcuenta = cmd2.Execute

        vMsgSalida=cmd2.Parameters("@msg_salida").value

        response.write("-")     
        response.write(vMsgSalida)      
        response.write("-")     

        Set Rs_crearcuenta = Nothing
response.end
```

Comment: For something as simple as a single char value (which happens to be numeric anyway) why not just use `RETURN 1` in the stored procedure,  then you can use the `adParamReturnValue` `ParameterDirectionEnum` which isn't blocked by the  `ADODB.Recordset` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@diana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690460/diana) has [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28685355/692942) you cannot access the output parameter because it isn't set until the query has executed.

This is a common problem and in this case you might think but I'm not executing a query that returns any results, I'm just inserting some data?

At first glance this may appear to be the case but when you take into consideration the use of

```sql
Select @msg_salida = '1'
```

you are in fact returning a single row single column `ADODB.Recordset` object.

In these instances using `SET` instead of `SELECT` is advisable because it does not create a `ADODB.Recordset` or block access to the `OUTPUT` parameters until all `ADODB.Recordset` objects are closed.

By changing the above line for example to

```sql
SET @msg_salida = '1'
```

and changing your `ADODB.Command` execute to

```vb
'Execute the command without returning any Recordsets
Call cmd2.Execute()
```

Comment: Thanks you! Both `SET` and `SELECT` works in the Procedure, but the thing here that was the key part for me, was changing from `set rds = cmd.Execute` to only do `Call cmd.Execute`. That made the output value be present in the parameter. Good tip!

Comment: @DanneManne you're welcome, its because a `ADODB.Recordset` blocks access to the output parameters until it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer on [Why adParamOutput parameter doesn't contain a value after execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057433/why-adparamoutput-parameter-doesnt-contain-a-value-after-execute?rq=1) explains:

You have to iterate through all records before you can read the output parameter, like

```
do until rs.EOF
     rs.MoveNext
loop
```

Comment: Or use `rs.GetRows()` to return an array and then close the `ADODB.Recordset` object. That way your array is available to iterate through regardless of whether you need to access output parameters.

Comment: Although [the answer you link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057433/why-adparamoutput-parameter-doesnt-contain-a-value-after-execute?rq=1) is correct, they don't explain why and make it appear as though you can never access `OUTPUT` parameters until all recordsets have been iterated. This is simply not true and I will be adding my own answer to that question to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was nothing to do with record sets being retrieved. Check if `On Error Resume Next` is being used in the Classic ASP script as there could be an MSSQL exception being swallowed that is causing the output parameter to never be set.